# Android sqlite pagination in TextView

Tags: android, pagination, android-sqlite

I am using Android studio with `SQLite` database is built-in, I am fetching some text from a table of 2 columns into `TextView`.

I want to use next and previous button 
When the `Activity` starts, it loads the first record of a table in `TextView` but when I click on next button it should fetch next row of the table in `TextView` and when I click previous it should fetch the previous row of the table.

I am new to Android I searched about that but unfortunately found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**try this. it could help you.**

when a user enters in Activity fetch all data from `Database` and store that data in `ArrayList` at particular index . On click of Next Button get data from  `ArrayList` according to it's `index`.